# Making php's loop understandable by server not just echoing the code

Tags: php, loops

I have to add a long kind of code

```
 $somephpcode->Cell($string1);
 $somephpcode->Cell('Figure 1');
 $somephpcode->Cell($string2);
 $somephpcode->Cell('Figure 2');
 $somephpcode->Cell($string3);
 $somephpcode->Cell('Figure 3');
 ...
```

I would like to make it quicker with a loop.
I can make it like that:

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 25; $x++) {
    $somestring = "\$somephpcode->Cell(\$string$x);\$somephpcode->Cell('Figure $x');";
    echo $somestring;
}
```

And it's gonna echo the right code. But my beginner question is how to make that understandable by server, not just return (show) the code? What should I use instead echo? Is it possible?

Comment: You make the $string variable an array and use $x to access the array slots in the loop: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any significant changes, you can just create a string that contains the name of the variable you want to refer to, and then use PHP's "variable variables" feature to dereference it:

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 25; $x++) {
    $varName = 'string' . $x;
    // So now $varName contains a string like "string1", and we use two dollar signs here:
    $somephpcode->Cell($$varName);
    $somephpcode->Cell('Figure ' . $x);
}
```

However, any time you have variables named like var1, var2, var3, you really should think about using an array instead. For example:

```
$strings = ['first string', 'second string', 'third string', ... ];
```

Then you can refer to the first string by its numerical index starting at zero, like `$strings[0]`. This makes your code much cleaner:

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 25; $x++) {
    $somephpcode->Cell($strings[$x - 1]);
    $somephpcode->Cell('Figure ' . $x);
}
```